# Fragment navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I'm creating an app, with one main activity and fragments.
I'm trying to control what will happen on backPress using this code on the mainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {        
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            this.finish();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

The structure of my app is this:
MainAtivity --> Fragment1 -->  Fragment2 --> Fragment2 ... (back Press should get me to Fragment1)
When I created Fragment2 I added Fragment1 to the backStack, and when pressing back I still see Fragment2 in the background.
How can I get to Fragment1 and only Fragment1 to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how do you commit your fragment. But this would helpful.

While commit:

```
 // Initialize a Fragment Transaction.
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Record all steps for the transaction.

 ft.replace(R.id.home_frame_layout_for_fragments, baseFragments[i],     

// Add the transaction to backStack with tag of first added fragment
ft.addToBackStack(baseFragments[0].getTagText());

// Commit the transaction.
ft.commit();
```

While removing:

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
while (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

This may works !!!

Happy coding !!!!

Comment: Thank you!
I think I understand better now how to navigate